# How to make my own StackProtector?

Tags: llvm

I am implementing my own stack protector in LLVM as a part of my college project. It need not be very advanced. I just need to protect my arrays from overflowing by making a compiler pass. I am thinking of increasing the size of my buffer by a random value each time the program is compiled (I know this is not a good way to control the overflow, but like I said it need not be very advanced). I did something on following lines:

```
for(Function::iterator Begin = F.begin(), End = F.end(); Begin!=End; ++Begin){
    for(BasicBlock::iterator I = Begin -> begin(), E = Begin -> end(); I != E; ++I){
        if(AllocaInst *instToReplace = dyn_cast<AllocaInst>(E){
            if(instToReplace -> isArrayAllocation()){
                randNo = rand() % 50 + 5;
                ReplaceInstWithInst(instToReplace -> getParent() -> getInstList, E, new AllocaInst(Type::ArrayType, randNo, "instToReplace");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm stuck on a couple of things.

1. LLVM doesn't have a `rand()` function (at least, as far as I have seen it).
2. My `ReplaceInstWithInst` is wrong as I'm replacing the same instruction with the same instruction, with a different size (although, that's precisely what I want).

Could anyone help me on how do I get about the two instructions?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to add an additional AllocInst instead of replacing the old?

Comment: Ya. Actually I didn't know that adding an additional AllocInst wouldn't cause a change in data.

Comment: It's possible that other instructions depend on the size of the AllocaInst. You can fix up the indexing (look for GetElementPtrInsts). I recommend looking at AddressSanitizer's implementation in LLVM. It also uses redzones for stack allocations.